# Resizing an Array with a Dedicated method for upsize and downsizing

Tags: java, arrays

I'm fairly new to coding and am struggling with an assignment for my class. The program takes a user input for the size of an Array and prompts the user to enter each value 1 at a time. The array size starts at 3 and if the array needs to be bigger when the array has filled a new array that's 2x size is created and all info is copied into it. I was able to figure out this part but I just can't see what I'm doing wrong in the downsizing part. After the info is copied I have to remove the trailing zeroes. I think I have the downsize method right but I don't know if I'm calling it right

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab6 {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int[] myarray = new int[3]; 
        int count = 0;
        int limit, limitcount = 1;

        Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("How many values would you like to enter? ");
        limit = kbd.nextInt();

        while (limitcount <= limit) {
            System.out.println("Enter an integer value ");
            int input = kbd.nextInt();
            limitcount++; 
            if (count < myarray.length) {
                myarray[count] = input;
          
            }
            else {
                myarray = upsize(myarray); 
                myarray[count] = input; 
            }
            count++; 
        }
  
        myarray = downsize(myarray, count)
  
        printArray(myarray);
        System.out.println("The amount of values in the arrays that we care about is: " + count);
    }

static int[] upsize(int[] array) {
    int[] bigger = new int[array.length * 2];
        for (int i =0;i<array.length; i++) {
            bigger[i] = array[i];
        }
    return bigger;
}

static void printArray( int[] array ) {
    for ( int number : array ) {
        System.out.print( number + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}

static int[] downsize(int[] array,int count) {
    int[] smaller = new int[count];
    for (int i =0; i<count; i++) {
        smaller[i] = array[i];
        }
        return array; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving you a full response rather than a comment since you're new here and I don't want to discourage you with brevity which could be misunderstood.

1. Not sure what happened to your code when you pasted it in here, you've provided everything but the format is weird (the 'code' bit is missing out a few lines at the top and bottom).  Might be one to double-check before posting.  After posting, I see that someone else has already edited your code to fix this one.
2. You're missing a semi-colon.  I'm not a fan of handing out answers, so I'll leave you to find it :)  If you're running your code in an IDE, it should already be flagging that one up for you.  If you're not, why on earth not???  IntelliJ is free, easy to get going with, and incredibly helpful.  There are others out there as well which different folk prefer :)  An IDE will help you spot all sorts of useful things quickly.
3. I have now run your code, and you do have a problem!  It's in your final method, `downsize()`.  Look very, very carefully at the return statement ;)  Your questions suggests you aren't actually sure whether or not this method is right, which makes me wonder: have you actually run this code with different inputs to see what results you get?  Please do that.
4. Style-wise: blank lines between methods would make the code easier to look at, by providing a visual gap between components.  Please be consistent with putting your opening { on the same line as the method signature, and with having spaces between items, e.g. `for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)` rather than `for (int i =0; i<count; i++)`.  The compiler couldn't care less, but it is easier for humans to look at and just makes it look like you did care.  Always a good thing!
5. I think it is awesome that you are separating some of the work into smaller methods.  Seriously.  For extra brownie points, think about how you could move that while() block into its own method, e.g. private int[] getUserData(int numberOfItems, Scanner scanner).  Your code is great without this, but the more you learn to write tiny units, the more favours you will be doing your future self.
6. Has your class looked at unit testing yet?  Trust me, if not, when you get to this you will realise just how important point 5 can be.  Unit tests will also help a lot with issues such as the one in point 3 above.

Overall, it looks pretty good to me.  Keep going!!!

Comment: Thank you after I was having trouble getting the whole code to format right when posting but someone seemed to edit that for me (thanks DevilsHnd). I have found the missing semicolon. It was a piece of the code I had edited as a was writing the post and forgot to change it in the browser. I did figure out the issue in the return statement thank you so much. My professor provided the file for us to edit in the methods and I'm guessing had it set to return array so that the program could run without a completed downsize() method.

Comment: As of point 5 and 6, I will look into it we haven't looked at unit testing yet so as long as it works (which it does thank you) I'm going to leave it as it is but I might comeback to it to see how I would go about changing it. Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 1):

Simple mistake in your downsize method. If you have an IDE like Eclipse, Intellij, etc. you would have seen it flagged right away.

```
return array; // should return smaller
```

I have a few suggestions since you mentioned being new to coding.

1. The "limitcount" variable can be removed and substituted with "count" at every instance. I'll leave it to you to figure that out.
2. Try using more descriptive and understandable variable names. Other people will read your code (like now) and appreciate it.
3. Try to use consistent spacing/indentation throughout your code.
4. Your upsize method can be simplified using a System.arraycopy() call which generally performs better and avoids the need for writing out a for loop. You can rewrite downsize in a similar manner.

```
static int[] upsize(int[] array) {
    int[] bigger = new int[array.length * 2];
    System.arraycopy(array, 0, bigger, 0, array.length);
    return bigger;
}
```

Edit: All good points by sunrise above - especially that you've done well given your experience. You should set up an IDE when you have the time, they're simple to use and invaluable. When you do so you should learn to step through a debugger to explore the state of your program over time. In this case you would have noticed that the myarray variable was never reassigned after the downsize() call, quickly leading you to a solution (if you had missed the warning about an unused "smaller" array).

Comment: Thanks for the tips I will look into the IDE Ive never heard of them before, As for the limitcount and count redundancy I was thinking that as well but some of the code was provided by the professor with parts that we have to figure out like creating the print array and downsize method while showing us the upsize one in class and thats how he did it.  Although yours looks a lot cleaner and simpler Im going to use the one he showed us. Also the spacing is probably due to him using spaces in the sample docs he gives us but I use tabs it is very irritating to line all his lines up with mine.

Comment: bliss has indeed provided several good tips here.  It sounds to me like your professor is (perhaps accidentally) giving you useful examples of why consistent and tidy formatting is so important :)  Also, I strongly second bliss's comment about stepping through your code in debugging mode.  I have resolved many of my own errors in that manner.  Get yourself an IDE and enjoy the enhancing learning!